# How to set JSX files default to Babel text highlighting in sublime

Tags: javascript, sublimetext3, babeljs

I have a babel text highlighting that i added in my sublime. However every time I open a new react project it defaults to javascript text highlighting then i have to reset each javascript file to get the correct text highlighting. As you can see in the lower right of my screenshot it is by default set to javascript.

[image]

Answer (score 94, accepted):

The syntax that Sublime selects is based primarily on the extension that the file has.

You can select `View > Syntax > Open all with current extension as...` from the menu while you have such a file open to tell Sublime what syntax you want it to use for any particular extension.

If you sometimes use regular JavaScript as well, you'll experience your current problem in reverse; you will have to manually swap the syntax back to JavaScript.

Either way, the [Project Specific Syntax Settings](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Project%20Specific%20Syntax%20Settings) package may also be useful in this case if you use projects. It will allow you to configure per project what you want the syntax for different files to be.

Answer (score 2):

What I did was to make babel(JavaScript) the default, preventing the default JavaScript by adding it as a value to ignored_packages.

To do this, open your sublime, click on Preferences > settings then paste this in:

```
"ignored_packages":["JavaScript"]
```

More details here: https://github.com/babel/babel-sublime

Comment: Note that some syntaxes in Sublime embed others, so disabling a package may cause issues. For example, the HTML syntax embeds the JavaScript syntax so that it can highlight the contents of `<script>` tags; ignoring the `JavaScript` package will stop that from working. Whether or not these things are breaking changes depends on your workflow, but something to be aware of.